# Show only Video Chromecast Devices for Playback

Tags: android, chromecast

I am developing a basic Android Sender Video App. I had configured the Receiver on Google Cast Console with the default Receiver URL and got hot of the app ID. I had implemented Chromecast in the Action Bar (Android) and onClick action provides the list of chromecast devices ready for casting. The list includes both Video and Audio Chromecast devices, since mine is a Video Player app how can I filter out the "Audio Chromecast" devices from the list ?

Cheers ..

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Comment: I also have the same issue now. Any solution?

Comment: @AkilaWasala vanlooverenkoen, anyone has the soultion for this?